# How to fetch a document data and set it on screen

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, future

I'm trying to fetch certain information from a firebase object (like the name) but the build doesn't wait for the future, nor changes it afterwords

I've tried both using a Future and a Stream (I'm assuming the stream would be less efficient but I'm super new to flutter)

I had this function to fetch the document I want (yes the propertyId is set!)

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot> _createPropertyInfoState() async{

    DocumentSnapshot doc =  await Firestore.instance.collection('properties').document(widget.propertyId).get();
    return doc;
  }
```

and in the build function I was calling it like so:

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: _createPropertyInfoState(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            propertyNameController = TextEditingController(text: snapshot.data['propertyName']);
            streetNameController = TextEditingController(text: snapshot.data['address']);
            boughtOnController = TextEditingController(text: snapshot.data['boughtOn']);
          } else {
            propertyNameController = TextEditingController();
            streetNameController = TextEditingController();
            boughtOnController = TextEditingController();
          }
          return null;
        });
```

I then tried to change it into a stream where i'd just call this function in build:

```
void _createPropertyInfoState() {
    StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('properties').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            propertyNameController = TextEditingController();
            streetNameController = TextEditingController();
            boughtOnController = TextEditingController();
          } else {
            propertyNameController = TextEditingController(
                text: snapshot.data.document[widget.propertyId]
                    ['propertyName']);
            streetNameController = TextEditingController(
                text: snapshot.data.document[widget.propertyId]['address']);
            boughtOnController = TextEditingController(
                text: snapshot.data.document[widget.propertyId]['boughtOn']);
          }
          return null;
        });
  }
```

I just want those exact values to be set